# Sending an email to set of users who has access to folder in SharePoint 2013 Document Library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, document

I have created a new site with Document center template. I have created several folders inside of a Document library and set unique permission to each folder by removing the inherited permissions. So each folder has different set of users.

I am creating one document in one folder (ex: Folder `B`). My Requirement is sending an email to all users who has an access to folder (Folder `B`) whenever new item is added. I could not able to get the users who are belongs to that folder.

Is there any way I can get this users email addresses for that folder using SharePoint 2010 Designer workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of assigning permissions individually, I would create various groups (even if the group is as basic as "People with access to Folder B") Then, you can create an alert when items are added or modified, which is sent to the same group to whom you gave the folder permission.

As I understand it, using groups to manage permissions is considered better practice than assigning access individually, especially if your groups have organizational meaning.

Comment: Hi bbadgett, Thanks for your answer. You are right. Creating the group will be the best approach rather than giving the access to folder individually. I will change to Group. I prefer to do this notification using SharePoint designer workflow than "Alert Me" feature. because  i can format the Email template and keep the logs for notifications. Can we acheive these two in "Alert Me" ?

Comment: As far as I know, the "alert me" feature is pretty barebones without much ability to customize.  A worfklow, I think, would be your better bet.

Comment: Hi bbadgett, Thanks for your answer. You are correct. I will go with SharePoint designer 2010 workflow. Thanks for your time .